# Android Pusher Singleton channel subscription

Tags: android, pusher

Hello I have implemented pusher for realtime chat and subscribing to pusher channel , but I have many activities and fragments where i want to listen to pushr events . I have added this code in every activity/fragment but the problem is that it creates multiple subscriptions for every id . I know that i have to use Singleton for this can anyone point me in the right direction to achieve this ?

Here is the code i am writing in every activity/fragment

```
 private PusherOptions options;
 private Channel channel;
 private Pusher pusher;    
 options = new PusherOptions();
 options.setCluster("ap2");
 pusher = new Pusher("afbfc1f591fd7b70190f", options);
 pusher.connect();

     profile_id = Global.shared().preferences.getString("PROFILE_ID", " ");

    channel = pusher.subscribe(profile_id);
    channel.bind("message",
            new SubscriptionEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onEvent(String s, String s1, final String data) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try {
                                JSONObject result = new JSONObject(data);
                                String message = result.getString("message");
                                String time = result.getString("time");
                                String reId = result.getString("recieverId");
                                new_message = message;
                                getConvoData(k, message);

                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                            System.out.println("DATA ====>>" + data);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

Comment: Have you tried putting Pusher instantiation code into you Application class? That's the simplest possible way to achieve only one instance per application that you can access from each Fragment/Activity.

A better way to do it would be to use something like Dagger for Dependency injection: https://google.github.io/dagger/

Comment: I was able to implment this correctly , thank you so much , now can you suggest me how can i reflect these changes in my activity/ fragment so that i can update my adapter listening to these pusher events , for example i want to listen to "message" event and update chat counter and chat list in ChatActivity , how can i achieve this by sending some data from global class to specific activity , Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can expose `channel` in your `Global` class. That will allow you to call `bind` and `unbind` in your fragments, when they are in the foreground.

`connectToPusher` should just create a channel and subscribe to it.

In `Global.java`:

```
private Channel channel;

public void connectTopusher() {
    PusherOptions options;
    Pusher pusher;
    options = new PusherOptions();
    options.setCluster("ap2");
    pusher = new Pusher("afbfc1f591fd7b70190f", options);
    pusher.connect();
    String profile = Global.shared().preferences.getString("PROFILE_ID", "");
    this.channel = pusher.subscribe(profile);
}

public Channel getChannel(){
    return this.channel;
}
```

And then in your activity/fragment you can bind/unbind your listeners to when they are resumed/paused - just keep a reference to it like this:

`YourActivity.java` (could also be your Fragment)

```
private SubscriptionEventListener messageListener = new SubscriptionEventListener(){
     @Override
    public void onEvent(String channel, String event, String data) {
        //TODO: do something with events
    }
}

//Bind when the listener comes into the foreground:
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    ((Global) getActivity().getApplication()).getChannel().bind("message", messageListener);

}

//Make sure to unbind the event listener!
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    ((Global) getActivity().getApplication()).getChannel().unbind("message", messageListener);
}
```

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks a lot again , will try this method

Comment: Thanks a lot man , you saved my day . This is working perfectly.

Comment: Good to hear that! :)

Answer (score 1):

okay so after trying for a while i figured it out my self i created a global class and just added pusher code to it so that it maintains just one connection for the entire lifecycle of the app

```
public class Global extends MultiDexApplication {

    @Override
        public void onCreate() {
            super.onCreate();

            SharedPreferences preferences = sharedInstance.getSharedPreferences(sharedInstance.getString(R.string.shared_preferences), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
            sharedInstance.preferences = preferences;
            connectTopusher();


        }

 public void connectTopusher() {
        PusherOptions options;
        Channel channel;
        Pusher pusher;
        options = new PusherOptions();
        options.setCluster("ap2");
        pusher = new Pusher("afbfc1f591fd7b70190f", options);
        pusher.connect();
        String profile = Global.shared().preferences.getString("PROFILE_ID", "");
        channel = pusher.subscribe(profile);

        channel.bind("message",
                new SubscriptionEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onEvent(String s, String s1, final String data) {
                        new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try {
                                    JSONObject result = new JSONObject(data);
                                    String message = result.getString("message");
                                    String time = result.getString("time");
                                    String reId = result.getString("recieverId");

                                } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                                System.out.println("DATA ====>>" + data);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });


        channel.bind("status_change", new SubscriptionEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(String s, String s1, final String data) {
                new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            JSONObject result = new JSONObject(data);

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        System.out.println("DATA ====>>" + data);
                    }
                });
            }


        });


    }
```